# Count the number of unique geometries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, unique-constraint

I have a table with over 32M rows that consists of line segments. I know that some of the line segments are duplicated (but there is no other unique ID). I need to know how many unique geometries there are in the database to be able to estimate run time for another process (i.e., I think I could limit run time if I filter out duplicates).

Comment: check this please: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could delete duplicates first and then count afterwards. Note, you will have to add a serial (id) to make this work. The `ST_DWithin` clause speeds it up if you have a spatial index added to your geometry column.

```
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name a
USING schema_name.table_name b 
WHERE a.id > b.id 
AND ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom)
AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 0);
```

And then `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema_name.table_name`. Alternatively you could count directly without deleting in the first place.

Comment: @Timorth Dalton Thanks for this. So, without creating another table I would just remove the "DELETE" command, correct?

Comment: You could try something like `SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_AsBinary(geom)) AS geom, id FROM schema_name.table_name`